# A RenderFlex overflowed by 55 pixels on the bottom (Android)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm newbie, still learning Flutter. I encountered the issue as mentioned in title. Hope there's someone can help me. My code as follow:

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  String email;
  String password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                //Do something with the user input.
              },
              decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your email'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                //Do something with the user input.
              },
              decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your password'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 24.0,
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              title: 'Log In',
              colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: (){
                print(email);
                print(password);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried several times, still can't find solution. Really appreciate if someone is there for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the height of the elements combined more than the screen height, and none of the widgets used are scrollable.

You can wrap the column in SingleChildScrollView (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) to make it scrollable.

But I am guessing that you do not want the user to scroll on the login screen. So I would suggest you change one of the SizedBoxes to Spacer (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) which will automatically take up the largest available space